# Count the number of instances where value in comma separated list

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table that holds comma separated values;

```
Column1
--------------------
ABC 21.17
ABC 21.17, ABC 21.18
ABC 21.16, ABC 21.17
```

And I am trying to count by each comma delimited value, so for example;

```
Column1           Count
----------        ----------
ABC 21.16         1
ABC 21.17         3
ABC 21.18         1
```

Comment: Do you have control over the table design?   The example above violates 1st normal form and should be redesigned...

Comment: Based on [this forum thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/3c8e2212-343f-4867-8ab0-2c636893056b/how-to-count-of-occurrences-of-a-character-inside-a-string?forum=sqlintegrationservices) you might want to count the numbers of commas and add 1. However this is not what SQL is intended for (you are violating NF1), I'd even go so far to say your design is flawed.

Comment: You seem to store numerical values anyway, so you should use a numerical type as well. Prefer integrals with fixed comma arithmetics over floating point, you spare quite a bit of trouble (in your example: store in 100th of a unit).

Comment: Splitting of strings using any delimiter (not just comma) is a question that is asked and answered every day. You split the string and then aggregate (i.e., count).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're on SQL Server 2016 (Compatibility Level 130) or above, you can use `STRING_SPLIT` with a `CROSS APPLY`:

```
--Create table variable with some test data
declare @inputData table (Column1 varchar(max))
insert into @inputData values ('ABC 21.17'),('ABC 21.17, ABC 21.18'),('ABC 21.16, ABC 21.17')

select trim(value) as Column1, count(*) as [count]
from @inputData
cross apply string_split(Column1, ',')
group by trim(value)
```

Which gives your desired output:

```
/-------------------\
|  Column1  | count |
|-----------|-------|
| ABC 21.16 |   1   |
| ABC 21.17 |   3   |
| ABC 21.18 |   1   |
\-------------------/
```

Comment: "SQL Server 2013"? That doesn't exist. 2012, 2014, 2016, 2017 and 2019 are the current versions in (extended) support. Compatibility Level 130 doesn't mean SQL Server 2013 it means the **specific** database in running at that compatibility level; 130 relates to SQL Server 2016 (version 13).

Comment: Yes, my bad, typo from me, I meant 2016, it's now been edited thanks to [Charlieface](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14868997/charlieface).